# UWP disable visual state or remove trigger

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager, adaptive-trigger

I have a UWP app and have a visual state trigger in xaml like so

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="850" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!-- <Setter Target="MenuGrid.Grid.Background" Value="LightYellow" /> -->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState"> ...
```

Now i would like to disable one of the visual states or remove the trigger completely programmatically in code. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to remove them completely.

```
// Stop the child Storyboad if there's one.
MyVisualState.Storyboard?.Stop();

// Remove all triggers.
foreach (var trigger in MyVisualState.StateTriggers)
{
    MyVisualState.StateTriggers.Remove(trigger);
}
```

However, I'd use the approach below so I can remove and add them back later. You will need to name all your `AdaptiveTrigger`s first.

```
// Remove a specific trigger.
MyVisualState.StateTriggers.Remove(MyTrigger);

// Add it back.
MyVisualState.StateTriggers.Add(MyTrigger);
```